# Which is the best approach among Autolayout or calculating the height using NSAttributedString, to implement dynamic height of an UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, nsattributedstring

I have followed the tutorial from http://raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout and implemented the same, but with the release of iOS 8.3, the above tutorial doesn't seem to be working.

Therefore i switched back to the following code which works absolutely fine

```
-(float)height :(NSMutableAttributedString*)string
{
  NSAttributedString *attributedText = string;

  CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(200, MAXFLOAT)
                                           options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                           context:nil];
  CGSize requiredSize = rect.size;
  return requiredSize.height;
}
```

and call the same in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
  CGFloat heightOfcell = [self height:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  return heightOfcell;
}
```

Can someone suggest a better way for doing the same in auto-layout and i am not using StoryBoard?

Comment: What is no longer working in that tutorial?

Comment: The content label doesn't increase in height as the text increases. i just added the following line "self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight=200" in viewDidLoad method and got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest use Autolatyout on cell's content view and give an Estimated Row Height in viewDidLoad like this `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200;` However this apporach may not support the Earlier versions of IOS.

Comment: I will introspect and put the above to make it work, thank you.